# PHP operator with wildcard "LIKE" equivalent

Tags: php

When I search the phrase "xperia" on my site, the url pattern changes to:

> domain.com/?s=xperia

I use this code then, to show the **sony** specific sidebar. Same goes for **nokia**

```
<?php 
if ( isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s']=="xperia") {
    get_sidebar('sony');
} else {
   if ( isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s']=="nokia") {
        get_sidebar('nokia');
    } else {
        get_sidebar('left');
    }
}
```

However, I also want the **sony** sidebar to appear if someone searches for anything else ( but the phrase contains the keyword "xperia") For example "xperia z2"

> domain.com/?s=xperia+z2

Can this `['s']=="xperia"` be modified to include a type of  xperia*  rule?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strstr.php

Comment: You can try `strstr` or `preg_match` functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `empty()` in case the search string is empty. Then `stripos()` will perform case insensitive search:

```
if ( empty($_GET['s']) === false && stripos($_GET['s'], 'xperia') !== false) {
    get_sidebar('sony');
} elseif ( empty($_GET['s']) === false && stripos($_GET['s'], 'nokia') !== false) {
    get_sidebar('nokia');
} else {
    get_sidebar('left');
}
```

I also used `elseif` to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Use `strpos`:

```
if(isset($_GET['s'] && strpos($_GET['s'], 'nokia') !== false)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a partial match, especially an inexact or loose match, you might find the [fnmatch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) function useful